# OpenSSL - saving Private Key from string and creating a self-signed x509 certificate

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, x509, private-key

I am using OpenSSl.crypto to create an X509 self signed certificate. I have a private key as a string and would like to use that key to sign the certificate. I am struggling to save the key from a string to the right format that I can then use to load as a PKey object to use with OpenSSL.crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key). I keep getting an error because its probably that I am not saving it in the right format. Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try using `class OpenSSL.crypto.PKey`to create pkey object
docs here: https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#pkey-objects

Comment: and then how would i load the key which is base64 encoded to the pkey object?